# Deriving the Cauchy point of the horizontal subproblem for large-scale trust-region SQP

Tags: nonlinear-programming, trust-regions

I am having difficulty deriving the Cauchy point of the  horizontal subproblem

$$
\overline{g}_k^T Z_k u + \frac{1}{2} u^T Z_k^T W_k Z_k u \;\;\;\;\mbox{subject to}\;\; \mid \mid Z_k u \mid\mid_2
$$

given in equation (1.5.9) of page 60 of this [thesis](https://camo.ici.ro/books/thesis/plant.ps) as

$$
-\alpha (Z_k^T Z_k)^{-1} Z_k^T \overline{g}_k
$$

From the little I know of how to calculate the Cauchy point it is obtained by substituting    $-\alpha g_k$ for $u$ in the subproblem, differentiating and equating to zero as shown below

$$
-\overline{g}_k^T Z_k g + \alpha \, g^T Z_k^T W_k Z_k g  = 0 
$$

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be leading anywhere near the expected result.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: What you have in the first line on the left is an expression you're trying to minimize, subject to a constraint. What is the general approach to constrained optimization? We start by writing down a Lagrangian, and then obtaining the optimality conditions from it!